# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el color de una sombra con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

tengo un div con una sombra creada en css, y quiero que al pulsar un botón la sombra cambie de color.

Este es el código javascript:

```js
function cambiarColor(propiedad) {
    document.getElementById(propiedad).style.box.shadow = red
}
```

¿Alguien sabe como puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar el siguiente código:

```
function cambiarColor(propiedad) {
    document.getElementById(propiedad).style.boxShadow = "20px 20px 30px red";
}
```

Donde los primeros dos parametros son la distancia a la que va a estar la sobra, el tercero la opacidad que va a tener y el último el color que quieras.

Si utilizas getElementById, no hace falta que le pases por parámetro el nombre, ya que lo puedes coger directamente.

Un saludo.